# cXML Processing and Samples

Tags: edi, cxml-commercexml

I have few questions related to [cXML (commerce eXtensible Markup Language)](http://cxml.org/). As I understand cXML document is constructed based on XML Document Type Definitions
(DTDs). Acting as templates, DTDs define the content model of a cXML document,
for example, the valid order and nesting of elements, and the data types of attributes.

Above brief introduction about cXML. What I am trying to achieve is to process cXML as we will receive cXML based invoices from suppliers and we need to import them to our ERP system and then process it appropriately. My initial questions are:

1) As per cXML User's guide (can be downloaded from the link above) - "All generated cXML documents must point to the DTDs at cXML.org, not the local DTDs". This means we cannot have our own DTDs?

2) Processing - Once we received the cXML based invoice from the supplier - how can we process it? I mean mapping of VAT-Code etcetera ? Is there any sample available? (.NET based)

I am un-able to find out much information on it apart from various people looking for creating cXML as [rampidbyter](http://www.rampidbyter.com/post/cXML-and-ASPNET.aspx). In short I am still un-able to find out any samples or any information on the processing of it.

Thanks for any pointers in advance...

Comment: I've done cXML integrations using translation software.  I modeled the cXML off of sample data, and then modeled my target (both flat file and database).  Same held true of the outbound - modeled my source (flat file and database) and modeled my target (cXML).  Drag/drop. Test. Move to production.  But I used software to do it, not created my own parser / generator.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to Question 1

You are receiving data from external system (I guess it’s from Ariba ) probably you don’t need to define DTD on your side. If you want validate received cXML data before processing you could validate using cXML.org respective invoice dtd link or download dtd and validate locally.

Answer to Question 2

cXML is XML so you can use any language (Java , C#) or middleware (Mule ESB, SAP PI,  BizTalk ) to parse in the format of target ERP system.

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:** you can have our own DTD's, but it should be valid and working and able to parse/validate the **incoming cXML.**

**Answer 2:** you can map the invoice in your ERP, map the field you required if you required more field the ask supplier to provide field as Extrinsic.

if you provide me your sample **invoice cXML** then and then I will provide you the sample code using C#.